# How to debug what matches a regex in a GNU Make target/prereq?

Tags: build, makefile, cygwin

I'm working in a huge legacy C project with a *GNU Make* based build system. One of the rules is used for dependency generation of dependencies. It looks like this:

```
%.d:%.c
   recipe
```

However, in *Cygwin*, this is complaining saying that I don't have any rules for the first foo.d file that it matches and it works perfectly under *Linux*, so I'm wondering what is *%.d* expanding to.

How can I debug that?

Answer (score 0):

See "Pattern Rules" in the GNU make manual.  The `%` matches any number of characters.  So if make wants to build a file `foo.d` then `%` matches `foo`, and in order for this rule to apply that means make must be able to find (or build) a file named `foo.c`.

Comment: I get the following error: "make[2]: *** No rule to make target `foo.d'.  Stop." And foo.c exists and can be built by make. What could cause this incorrect behavior?

Comment: The first thing you might try is adding some whitespace, as in `%.d : %.c`.  On Windows sometimes there is confusion between target definitions and drive letters in pathnames, so it's better to use whitespace around colon characters.  If that doesn't help you should run `make -d` and try to figure out why make is rejecting that rule.  The output is voluminous but should be illuminating.